# Web browser opening websites in mobile mode instead of desktop mode

Tags: qt, webbrowser-control

I would like to make an application which accesses a website (like Google Keep online), but instead of opening it in desktop mode, my application (technically, a web browser) could open it in mobile mode.

I have already tried using a URL like this : "m.website-url.com", thinking that this will open website in mobile mode. It works for facebook and many other websites, but I am unable to do this with Google Keep.

Please take care that I am using Qt Creator for making my app, but if you have the solution on how I can achieve this in any other language, let me know.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can't guarantee that a website even has a mobile version, but the general way to retrieve the mobile version is to specify your user-agent. But what have you tried so far? Do you have any working or non-working code already that we could start with?

Comment: Hello owacoder, thanks for such a quick reply. I should tell you that, i have just written a code to make a web browser which can simply open websites. I have not written anything regarding the mobile version of the website.